# Bochner Integral: Primitive

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lebesgue-integral

Given a Banach space $E$.

Consider a continuous function:
$$F\in\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R},E):\quad\int_\mathbb{R}\|F(s)\|\mathrm{d}s<\infty$$

Then it has a primitive:
$$G(t):=\int_0^tF(s)\mathrm{d}s:\quad G'(t)=F(t)$$
How to prove this abstractly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This answer is community wiki.*

By Hahn-Banach one has:
$$F\in\mathcal{L}(\Omega):\quad\frac{1}{\lambda(\Omega)}\int_\Omega F(s)\mathrm{d}s\in\overline{\langle F(\Omega)\rangle}$$

By continuity one has:
$$F\in\mathcal{C}(\Omega,E):\quad\overline{\langle FB_\varepsilon(z)\rangle}\stackrel{\varepsilon\to0}{\to}F(z)$$

So one obtains:
$$\frac{1}{h}\{G(t+h)-G(t)\}=\frac{1}{h}\int_t^{t+h}F(s)\mathrm{d}s\to F(t)$$
*(This prove imitates the usual one.)*